# Recursively checking the status of a job on GitLab with Axios

Tags: node.js, async-await, axios

I'm trying to get the job logs of a job that has a specific status (successful). I've decided to go with recursion but I keep reaching a read time out after a certain amount of time :

```
//Trigger pipelines
    await axios.post(`https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID_CREATE}/trigger/pipeline?token=${CREATE_TOKEN}&ref=terraform-v1-mirror`)
        .then(async (gitlabPOSTRequest) => {
                pipelineId = gitlabPOSTRequest.data.id
                console.log(`pipeline_id = ${pipelineId}`)
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error)
            }
        )

    let config = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID_CREATE}/pipelines/${pipelineId}/jobs?scope[]=success`,
        headers: {
            "PRIVATE-TOKEN": PRIVATE_TOKEN
        }
    }
    //Get Job Id
    await axios(config)
        .then(async (gitlabGETRequest) => {
                for (let gitLabResponse in gitlabGETRequest){
                    if(JSON.stringify(gitLabResponse.data.name)=='apply'){
                        jobId = JSON.stringify(gitLabResponse.data.id)
                    }else {
                        await axios(config)
                    }
                }
                console.log(`Job id : ${JSON.stringify(gitlabGETRequest.data[2].id)}`)
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error)
            }
        )
```

Am I doing it the right way? Is it the several GET requests that are pissing off the GitLab server?

Answer (score 0):

just use scope params like :

> curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID_CREATE}/pipelines/${pipelineId}/jobs?scope[]=success"

source : [DOC](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but since the response is dynamic the job I want won't be necessarily displayed. 
Therefore it got to stay recursive. 
I updated the code

Comment: why it must be recursive ? what do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: I'm triggering a pipeline via the API, and waiting for the specific job I'm monitoring to be completed so I could immediately get its logs. So I need to continuously do GET requests and check their responses.

Comment: i think its better to create specific route on nodejs and use webhook (on jobs events), 
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html

Comment: to do some test : https://repl.it/@AurelioLIMA1/StudiousSubstantialPixel